# Unable to export Powershell results

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm completely new to Powershell and trying to learn as I go. I have a requirement to find all AD users whose passwords have not been reset within the last 365 days, I also need to pull various other fields such as lastlogontimestamp, manager, cn, distinguishedname etc. I have tried the code below and it will show some results in the powershell window but as I have quite a few columns I really need to export - however whenever I try to export I get the following error:

```
Export-Csv : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null.
At line:6 char:12
+ $outList | Export-Csv -path D:\scripts\test.xml -NoTypeInformation
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Export-Csv], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ExportCsvCommand
```

Code I am using displayed below. Any help much appreciated.

```
`Get-AdUser -Filter 'Enabled -eq $True' -Properties Name, PasswordLastSet, PasswordNeverExpires, SamAccountName, accountExpires, Company, Description, cn, distinguishedName, info,lastLogonTimestamp, manager |
Where-Object {
$_.PasswordLastSet -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-365)
} |
Format-Table Name, SamAccountName, PasswordLastSet, PasswordNeverExpires, Company, Description, cn, distinguishedName, info, lastLogonTimestamp, manager
$outList | Export-Csv -path D:\scripts\test.xml -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: What's in `$outlist`? And youre using `Export-Csv` while pointing to an XML. Use `Export-CLIXml`

Comment: the error msg is pretty direct - there is nothing in your `$OutList` variable - or there is at least one null item. ///// this >>> `-Filter 'Enabled -eq $True'` is not going to work since you used SINGLE quotes around it. that means the `-eq` is testing against the literal value `$True` instead of the boolean true. [*grin*] change the outer quotes to DOUBLE quotes to allow the `$True` to be expanded to a boolean.

Answer (score 2):

When you run the `Get-ADUser` command it returns certain properties by default - you only need to specify the non-standard properties that you require. In your case there is no need to specify name and SamAccountName.

```
$outList = Get-AdUser -Filter 'Enabled -eq $True' -Properties PasswordLastSet, PasswordNeverExpires, accountExpires, Company, Description, cn, distinguishedName, info,lastLogonTimestamp, manager | Where-Object { $_.PasswordLastSet -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-365)}
```

The command `Format-Table` only refers screen output. To select properties from an object, use `Select-Object`

```
$outList | Select-Object Name, SamAccountName, PasswordLastSet, PasswordNeverExpires, Company, Description, cn, distinguishedName, info, lastLogonTimestamp, manager | Export-Csv -Path D:\scripts\test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

TThe above as a one-line command:

```
Get-AdUser -Filter 'Enabled -eq $True' -Properties PasswordLastSet, PasswordNeverExpires, accountExpires, Company, Description, cn, distinguishedName, info,lastLogonTimestamp, manager | Where-Object { $_.PasswordLastSet -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-365)} | Select-Object Name, SamAccountName, PasswordLastSet, PasswordNeverExpires, Company, Description, cn, distinguishedName, info, lastLogonTimestamp, manager | Export-Csv -Path C:\temp\test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```